# What does it mean that "the solution to a differential equation represents a vector field"

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone demonstrate why the solution to a differential equation i.e. $du/dx = u$ represents a vector field?

What is deep interpretation of this fact?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? One possible statement is that a solution $u$, regarded as a parameterized curve $x \mapsto (x, u(x))$, is an integral curve of the vector field $\left(1, \frac{du}{dx}\right)$ (and vice versa).

Comment: Usually we would say the **differential equation** represents a vector field, not the solution.

Comment: @Robert Israel and since any nth order ODE is a system of first order we assosiate the equation with the vectors field related to the system in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x$ say you that the function $y(x)$ has slope $x$ at a point of his graph with abscissa $x$. You can represent this slope with a  vector parallel to the straight line having such slope and attached to the point $(x,y)$ and all this vectors are a vector field. You can see [here](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/slope/slope1.html) for a graphical representation.